# Capturing regex groups with more than one special characters

Tags: java, regex

I am having trouble capturing a value from a string.
I have an input but it doesn't have any format just we know that its separated with `;` special character.

```
test?test; 1231@test;name=vonnegut
```

I would like to split this input with given special character and then find the result which includes another special character like `=`.

The result for this: `name=vonnegut`

Comment: Those characters aren't very "special"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
[^;]+=[^;]+
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32e3o)

`[^;]+` is a negated character class that will match a series of characters (`+` means at least one) that are not a semicolon (it will also match newline characters, so be careful if your string contains those, then you need to add them into the class `[^;\r\n]`)

Comment: That is a very elegant solution + a nice link.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the split() method for strings, it should do exactly what you want.

Split on ";" first and then on "=" on the resulting strings.

Comment: actually i could do it with split(";") method and then search for the other charachter but it s quite heavy to do that. maybe there is a way to handle it with one regex expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "test?test; 1231@test;name=vonnegut";
String[] splittedInput = input.split(",");
for (String str:splittedInput) {
  System.out.println(str);
}
```

gives you

> test?test
>    1231@test
>   name=vonnegut

Now you can test each individual string for your next character, for instance:

```
for (String str:splittedInput) {
  if (str.contains("=") {
    System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

You could also directly have a regex search. I would have to look that one up (don't use regex that often), but you'll figure that out easy enough. Probably there is already an answer containing the correct regex... ;)

Comment: thanks a lot but i have already done that. i am really new on this area just wonder why did you say: don't use regex that often? thank you a lot!

Comment: Then I suggest you declare that in your question (so it can better help others). And as you already got an accepted answer, please give him also an upvote (the `^` on the left side, above the green accept checkmark). You can award him with that. (And in my opinion he earned it, because his answer is exactly what you were looking for.)

Comment: I don't use regex that often because I don't have a grasp on the syntax. And I don't have a grasp of the syntax because I don't use it often. It's a viscous circle of lazyness... ;) Regex is a wonderfull tool. I encourage you to use it (more often than me :P).

Comment: :)  thank you i would like to award him but seems that i have to get 15 reputation for this.